# Python GUI and Class Structure

Tags: python, class, user-interface

Would it be good structure to have the "root" or "app" and mainloop in a class with a Frame instead of seperate and then if the "if __name.." to call?

example:

```
class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.title("Color Send to Arduino")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good reason to put your app code in a class that inherits from `Frame` is that it makes your code more reusable. You can insert it into any Tkinter GUI root without too much hassle.

For example in app.py

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def initialise(self):
        pass
```

and in other_app.py

```
from app import App
import Tkinter as tk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    myapp = App(root)
    myapp.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: To go along with my comment below, an actual (albeit extremely simple) reusable app would be a clock.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import getpass
import time

class WelcomeClock(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.timevar = tk.StringVar()
        self.__set_time()
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        message = "Welcome %s!\nThe time is currently"%(getpass.getuser().capitalize())
        self.welcome = tk.Label(self,text=message)
        self.welcome.pack(anchor=tk.N)
        self.clock = tk.Label(self,textvar=self.timevar)
        self.clock.pack()

    def __set_time(self):
        self.timevar.set(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
        self.after(499,self.__set_time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    clock = WelcomeClock(root)
    clock.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

As the `WelcomeClock` class inherits from `tk.Frame` I can easily import it and pack it into any other Tkinter GUI I use.

Comment: Great example! So it would make the code more reusable to leave the `root = tk.Tk()` and the `root.mainloop()` of the class in app.py?  Or should I include it because in other_app.py you could just write `myapp = App()`?  Sorry I'm new to both GUI design and OOP...

Comment: Personally I would leave the them both out of the class and put them in an if statement (like I have added to the code) so that they are only executed in the file that is actually being run. A good way to think about this is that you may want to have multiple "apps" in a GUI, but you only ever want to run `root.mainloop` once. With the above design, you can add or remove apps from your GUI with very little fuss.

Answer (score 0):

When you using  `class` you can use multiple time there methods using a create class  object.

```
import Tkinter

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        pass 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
```